# Detecting multiple keys in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm following along with a tutorial about creating a mini-RTS in Unity, but I've hit something of a roadblock when it comes to the selection feature for assigning selection groups for multiple units.
The pertinent parts are below:
In the Update() method of my UnitsSelection class

```
//manage selection groups with alphanumeric keys
    if (Input.anyKeyDown)
    {
        int alphaKey = Utils.GetAlphaKeyValue(Input.inputString);
        if (alphaKey != -1)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightControl)) 
            {
                _CreateSelectionGroup(alphaKey);
            }
            else
            {
                _ReselectGroup(alphaKey);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the GetAlphaKeyValue method from Utils:

```
public static int GetAlphaKeyValue(string inputString)
{
    if (inputString == "0") return 0;
    if (inputString == "1") return 1;
    if (inputString == "2") return 2;
    if (inputString == "3") return 3;
    if (inputString == "4") return 4;
    if (inputString == "5") return 5;
    if (inputString == "6") return 6;
    if (inputString == "7") return 7;
    if (inputString == "8") return 8;
    if (inputString == "9") return 9;
    return -1;
}
```

This is the code that is used in the tutorial, but to my understanding there is no way that _CreateSelectionGroup() would ever be called.

I've seen the tutorial demonstrate this functionality working, but whenever I try to run it GetAlphaKeyValue turns the Left and Right control keys into a -1 value so the if statement that checks for them never runs.
Am I missing something here? How does Unity normally handle things like Ctrl+1?

Comment: Print ```inputString``` in ```GetAlphaKeyValue``` and see what it prints.

Comment: Have you turned Num Lock on?

Answer (score 0):

*If* you use the `inputString` I would always rather check for `Contains` instead of an exact string match. However, I tried to use the `inputString` in the past and I found it too unpredictable for most usecases ^^

While holding control keys your Keyboard most likely simply won't generate any `inputString`.

> Only ASCII characters are contained in the inputString.

But e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will not generate the ASCII symbol `1` but rather a "non-printing character", a control symbol - or simply none at all.

---

You should probably rather use e.g.

```
public static bool GetAlphaKeyValue(out int alphaKey)
{
    alphaKey = -1;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha0) alphaKey = 0;
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1) alphaKey = 1;
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2) alphaKey = 2;
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha3) alphaKey = 3;
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha4) alphaKey = 4;
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha5) alphaKey = 5;
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha6) alphaKey = 6;
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha7) alphaKey = 7;
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha8) alphaKey = 8;
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha9) alphaKey = 9;

    return alphaKey >= 0;
}
```

And then use it like

```
//manage selection groups with alphanumeric keys
if(Utils.GetAlphaKeyValue(out var alphaKey)
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightControl)) 
    {
       _CreateSelectionGroup(alphaKey);
    }
    else
    {
        _ReselectGroup(alphaKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but same situation as before. Whenever I hold left or right control the GetAlphaKeyValue returns false and nothing else happens.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out it may just be an issue with my keyboard. Different keyboards handle key presses in different ways. Mine just refuses to tell Unity that control + (some other key) are being pressed together. Changed the code to respond to Shift + (some other key) and it works fine.